# Android Checkbox selection issue

Tags: android, checkbox

I am developing android app which has a registration form  which will be submitted as SMS. It contains checkboxes so the user can select one more check boxes.my issue I don't know how to make the selected box appear in the SMS when the user clicks submit. Any idea guys?

Comment: Please show some of your relevant code

Comment: i have only the code for textfields only, cause i had no idea how to write the code for checkbox